# Replace all the elements in a list at a given level with the level number

Tags: map, pure-function

How can I change the function `replace` in a pure function way?

```
replace[list_List, n_] := (g[a_] := n; Map[g, list, {n}]);
```

I tried

```
replace[list_List, n_] := Map[(#=n)&, list, {n}];
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: An input/output example would help. But I think you simply want `Map[n&, list, {n}];` if I understand your attempt correctly?

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh yes this works, that's exactly what I mean, thank you! And what does # represent when an input is list? Does it ignore all the levels? And can I represent list[[i]] using # and & (list is the input)?

Comment: `#` is just the first argument of the function, regardless of whether it's an atom, or a list, or some other expression. If you want to the first list element, you just use `#[[1]]`. Alternatively, look into `Apply` which can be used similarly to `Map`, but where individual list elements are passed as separate arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

```
replace[list_List, n_] := Map[n&, list, {n}];
```

I'm not sure why you were trying to assign `n` to the unnamed function's argument (which is not possible), but all you want is a function that returns `n` unconditionally, and `n&` is such a function.